# nya-bs-select with boolean ng-model

Tags: angularjs

How do I get `nya-bs-select` to use a boolean value on the model?

This is in the view:

```
<ol id="submitted" class="nya-bs-select" ng-model="submitted" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">
    <li class="nya-bs-option" value="true">
      <a>Submitted</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nya-bs-option" value="false">
      <a>Not Submitted</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

Here is the controller:

```
$scope.submitted=true;
// $scope.submitted="true";
```

Here is the full plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/iMvRDEr6s9zT6C34gM1y?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is by using an object as option and not a value like in this **[demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/l9BAs2dnZJ5Sf7XFKYL1?p=preview)**:

#### View

```
<ol class="nya-bs-select" ng-model="myModel">
    <li nya-bs-option="option in options">
        <a>{{option.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

#### Application

```
var app = angular.module('plunkerApp', ['nya.bootstrap.select']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.options = [
    {
      value: true,
      name: 'TRUE SELECTED'
    }, {
      value: false,
      name: 'FALSE SELECTED'
    },
  ];
});
```